# how to get CSS keyboard help for styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styles, styled-components

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSfco.png)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0v2C.png)
1-is it possible to get colored typed text for styled-components like the tutorial i'am watch in the video at left in the second image? i hate this red text :(

2-is it possible to get CSS support for styled-components like in second image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension from visualstudio market place [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components). It provides the Syntax highlighting and IntelliSense for for styled-components. (check below screenshot)

[image]

[image]